# How to catch combobox itemclick event in a controller

Tags: javascript, extjs

I know how to catch "regular" events in controllers, like those defined in listeners, but I do not know how to catch itemclick event, which is somewhat different. If I did not use a controller, I would do it like so:

```
xtype: 'combobox',
...,
itemId: 'some_id',
listConfig: {
    listeners:{
        'itemclick':{
                fn: function(view, node) {

                    ... do something

                }
         }
    }
 }
```

But how can I catch this event in the controller:

```
...
init:function(){
    this.control({
         ... how ???
```

I tried this:

```
    this.control({
        '[itemId=some_id]':{
            itemclick: this.doSomething
        },
        ...
```

and it does not work. So, I guess, there is something special about this event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ext.form.field.ComboBox](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox) is extension of [Ext.form.field.Picker](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Picker) and its [picker](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/source/ComboBox.html#Ext-form-field-ComboBox) is [Ext.view.BoundListView](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.view.BoundList)

```
createPicker: function() {
    var me = this,
        picker,
        pickerCfg = Ext.apply({
            xtype: 'boundlist',
            pickerField: me,
            selModel: {
                mode: me.multiSelect ? 'SIMPLE' : 'SINGLE'
            },
            floating: true,
            hidden: true,
            store: me.store,
            displayField: me.displayField,
            focusOnToFront: false,
            pageSize: me.pageSize,
            tpl: me.tpl
        }, me.listConfig, me.defaultListConfig);

    picker = me.picker = Ext.widget(pickerCfg);
    if (me.pageSize) {
        picker.pagingToolbar.on('beforechange', me.onPageChange, me);
    }

    ...
},
```

so you can try something like

```
this.control({
    'combo[name=myCombo] boundlist': {
        itemclick: this.myHandler
    }
});
```